# python multiprocessing get() performance

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I'm decoding messages using multiprocessing on python. I have 20 workers. Workers decoding messages. After decoding message size ~0.1 - 1MB.

```
def do_work(message):
    try:
        msg = pickle.loads(message[1])
        decoded_msg = codec.DECODE(Message(**msg).content)
    except:
        decoded_msg = "Unable to decode message"
```

I have around 2k - 5k msgs. Decoding process is relatively fast. But when I'm trying to receive results from worker:

```
decoded_msg.append(outQ.get())
```

it's incredibly slow.

My question is why receiving process is so slow and how to increase it's performance?

Comment: As a start have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: What kind of object is `outQ`?

Comment: `code`q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
outQ = multiprocessing.Queue()`code`

Answer (score 0):

decoded_msg is an object. So if I convert it to string first, then receive it by outQ.get() and then make it as an object again then this process is lightning fast.